# Express.js not able to parse the value coming from database

Tags: api, rest, express

I have express api with mysql db.For some reason I am not able to print the value of sub array array coming from db, however if I console.log(menu) it's printing fine.
Error showing is "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'monday')". Spent 2 hours but not getting any solution, thanks in advance.
Here is my code

```
let menu = JSON.parse(Item.personal_custom_menu);
              console.log(menu.monday);
```

Value for Item.personal_custom_menu which is coming from db is this

```
{
"monday":[{"title":"Lasagna","id":45},{"title":"Khawsey Curry","id":42},{"title":"Khawsey Curry","id":42}],
"tuesday":[{"title":"Khawsey Curry","id":42},{"title":"Khawsey Curry","id":42},{"title":"Khawsey Curry","id":42}],
"wednesday":[{"title":"Khawsey Curry","id":42},{"title":"Khawsey Curry","id":42},{"title":"Khawsey Curry","id":42}],
"thursday":[{"title":"Khawsey Curry","id":42},{"title":"Khawsey Curry","id":42},{"title":"Khawsey Curry","id":42}],
"friday":[{"title":"Khawsey Curry","id":42},{"title":"Khawsey Curry","id":42},{"title":"Khawsey Curry","id":42}],
"saturday":[{"title":"Khawsey Curry","id":42},{"title":"Khawsey Curry","id":42},{"title":"Khawsey Curry","id":42}],
"sunday":[{"title":"Khawsey Curry","id":42},{"title":"Khawsey Curry","id":42},{"title":"Khawsey Curry","id":42}]}
```

Comment: Seems the `menu` variable is null when you're trying to read `.monday`, that's the error. Could you tell us what ORM or connection driver are you using to get data from the db? also, could you share what happens if you `console.log(Item)`? is it actually coming from the db as a string?

Comment: I am using  pool.query, Console.log(Item) shows data as js object which is fine, what I need. JSON.parse(Item.personal_custom_menu) also console.log fine as js object, but only problem is item,personal_custom_menu.monday which is menu.monday is not accessible...